# jqGrid PHP Suite: how to get last inserted id

Tags: php, jqgrid

we are using jqGrid Suite PHP from Guriddo.

I'm using authomatic add feature, using form editing.
After the add operation I would need to get the last inserted id of the record to use it to perform an insert in another table.

If I understood well, looking at some other posts, the following code works only if I disable authomatic CRUD, and I perform manual add:

```
$lastpid = jqGridDB::lastInsertId($conn, 'qb_profiles', 'ProfileId', 'mysql');
```

Instead is there any way to get the last inserted id, using authomatic add feature by integrated form?

kind regards,
Matt